# Erlang Load balancer

Tags: erlang, distributed

Load balancer must know all the nodes. Clients will interface with load balancer, who then gives each task to node.

How can there be no single point of failure if client always accesses same (single) load balancer? You cannot have two load balancers, otherwise how will client know which one to connect to?

Is it accepted that for some parts of design you cannot avoid single point failure?

Comment: Incase i not find exactly what you mean, could you elaborate slightly more thanks

Comment: ok i have looked up your thing. i am asking how to do this specific to erlang, but thank you for the link

Comment: Doh - sorry, I missed the tag and you didn't mention erlang in your post - my bad.

Comment: My erlnag-foo is still weak (I'm actually working on learning it at the moment) but maybe this would help? http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distributed-otp-applications

Answer (score 8):

Having more than one load balancer as part of a highly available solution is very common, and there is no need for the load balancer to be a single point of failure. The load balancers can e.g. be placed behind a single virtual IP address that floats between them. If one goes down the IP floats over to the other one which takes over. The client is only aware of the single virtual IP which it always connects to.

If the clients are Erlang nodes and the communication takes place through Erlang messaging (missed this when providing the first part of the answer), you can set up the load balancing processes to belong to a process group (pg2) and rout through this. This would allow you to have multiple load balancers sharing the load. If all requests have to go through a single process for routing, you could register one process as global and have identical processes deployed on other nodes as a backup. These backups would need to monitor the global service, and take over if the global process is lost.

Comment: No it is not. Setting up virtual IPs is system administration/network configuration.

Comment: @ChristianDahlqvist Read the comments - this is an erlang specific question; I overlooked that the first time as well and commented similarly. Erlang has built-in networking and processes are distributed among nodes - he's talking about an erlang process (load balancer) rather than a network/IP load balancer.

Comment: I saw that this is listed as an Erlang question, but in my experience this is usually not handled at the application level, but rather through network configuration, which is what I have tried to describe.

Comment: It's ... different. A load balancer in erlang is a process receiving messages from other erlang processes and then load balancing them out to a set of other erlang processes running locally and remotely. It's more like using middleware where a queue is balanced to multiple processes. You could have all of that on one machine (erlang VM), or multiple nodes.

Comment: Is this the case when the clients are also Erlang nodes and the messaging takes place through Erlang messaging?

Comment: Right. You have N worker processes and need to balance work (being sent as messages from other erlang processes) across them, as well as monitor failed workers, etc. So your "clients" send messages to a balancer (or "manager") process that handles that. **Edit** Yup - your edit nails it.

Comment: Hah, I knew your name sounded familiar for some reason ... riak mailing list. Now I feel silly explaining that to you.

Comment: What mean by process group? Thank you

Comment: Look at the pg2 module in the Erlang documentation (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/pg2.html). This allows processes to be linked to a global group. Clients can then look up which processes that belong to a group and select one of the processes. This could work if you can have several load balancers balancing load individually.

Comment: Would this ask client to decide? I was going to not make client see different processes- treat them like only one process was there

Comment: You could wrap up the look-up and selection logic in a module and expose that to the client. This would hide the logic from the client and provide a simple to use interface.